# react native populate value in input field

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am new to react native. For a native base text component `Input`

```
<InputGroup rounded style={{width:deviceWidth/2+80,borderColor:'black'}}>
<Input keyboardType='numeric' placeholder='Phone Number' onChangeText={(text) => OrderViewStore.phone=text} value={OrderViewStore.phone}/>
</InputGroup>
```

i am trying to populate a integer value in  `value={OrderViewStore.phone}/>` it throws error 
`Invalid prop`value`of type`number`supplied to`TextInput`, expected`string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the integer to string.

```
value={OrderViewStore.phone.toString()}
```